# Vue.js - template doesn't update when variable value change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have like this action in my app where I manupulate data inside `created` hook:

**HTML** template example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">{{ item.title }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

> Note: As template in my app I use [vue grid layout](https://jbaysolutions.github.io/vue-grid-layout) package really

**Working code:**

```
created () {
  if(Array.isArray(this.predefinedItems)) {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.predefinedItems.length; index++) {
      this.items[index] = {...this.predefinedItems[index], ...{
        i: index, x: 1, y: 1, w: 12, h: 8, accent: 'info'
      }}
    }
    console.log(this.items)
  }
}
```

**Not working code:**

```
created() {
  this.emulateApiRequest()
}

methods: {
  emulateApiRequest() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (Array.isArray(this.predefinedItems)) {
        for (let index = 0; index < this.predefinedItems.length; index++) {
          this.items[index] = {
            ...this.predefinedItems[index],
            ...{ i: index, x: 1, y: 1, w: 12, h: 8, accent: 'info'
            }
          }
        }
        console.log(this.items)
      }
    }, 500)
  },
}
```

Why my template not updates when I emulate api request to set data?

Comment: Try going through the common beginner gotchas page, as well as the page on array's reactivity and array mutations.

Comment: I must use global `$set` method to update my array then?@NickM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're editing `items[]` by index directly, which [cannot be automatically detected in Vue 2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays). The first example only works because the `created()` hook occurs before the template is evaluated. The second example asynchronously updates `items[]`, occuring after the `created()` hook and after the template has been evaluated.

However, Vue 2 can detect `Array.prototype.push()` for item insertion into an array:

```js
for (let index = 0; index < this.predefinedItems.length; index++) {
  // this.items[index] = /*...*/
  this.items.push(/*...*/)
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-jennings-1m94i?file=/src/App.vue)

Alternatively, you could set `items[]` to a new array instance:

```js
const items = []
for (let index = 0; index < this.predefinedItems.length; index++) {
  items[index] = /*...*/
}
this.items = items
```

Or replace the `for`-loop with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), mapping `predefinedItems` into a new array:

```js
this.items = this.predefinedItems.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  i: index, x: 1, y: 1, w: 12, h: 8, accent: 'info'
}))
```